# What does the symbol [/] mean in NHibernate Profiler?

Tags: nhibernate, nhprof

What does this little symbol mean in NHProf? Why is it there in Session #1 but not Session #3?

[image: NHProf]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[]` section represents the URL that this session is bound to. `[/]` means the root URL of your application.

*Session #3* has not been executed from the *asp.net pipeline* (NHibernate may be used from a background thread), and there is no URL to show.